# How can I create a summary value of a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How I do summary value of php array ?

I want to display result like this.
DEVICE_1 : LOW=1,MEDIUM=0,HIGHT=0;
DEVICE_2 : LOW=2,MEDIUM=0,HIGHT=0;
DEVICE_3 : LOW=0,MEDIUM=1,HIGHT=2;

This is some data from my business api service

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_1
            [1] => LOW
            [2] => STAGE_1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_2
            [1] => LOW
            [2] => STAGE_1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_2
            [1] => LOW
            [2] => STAGE_2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_3
            [1] => MEDIUM
            [2] => STAGE_1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_3
            [1] => HIGHT
            [2] => STAGE_2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEVICE_3
            [1] => HIGHT
            [2] => STAGE_3
        )

)
```

Comment: Use a simple loop to group the elements together,

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the mappings such as `LOW = 1?` Replace in the inner loop with your mappings.

```
foreach ( $array as $device ) {
    $deviceInfo = '';
    foreach ( $device as $specs ) {
         $deviceInfo .= $specs . ' ';
    }
    echo $deviceInfo;
}
```